# Isolated positive derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Is it possible that a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $f'(p)>0$ for some $p$ but for all $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{p\}$, $f'(x)\le0$?

I made this question up myself, knowing basic calculus, and thought about it for a while, but couldn't come up with anything. Nevertheless I think it's an interesting problem.

Comment: *Hint:* Apply the mean-value theorem to $\frac{f(x) - f(p)}{x-p}$.

Comment: See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) to see what context you could provide.

Comment: By Darboux theorm, it is not possible.

Comment: "I know basic calculus" is not sufficient context.  This question must be motivated by *something*.  What caused you to ask it?  Was this problem posed as homework?  on an exam?  or is it something that you came up with on your own?  If you came up with it on your own, what made you think that such a function might exist (or that it might not)?

Comment: @PONPON I am telling you, as a moderator of this website, that the context you have provided is not in line with the expectations of this site.  If you want your question reopened, please edit it to include better context (e.g. by answering the questions I asked you in my previous comment).

Comment: @PONPON Don't post a discussion in the question. There's a good reason to ask for more context and show your advances on the problem: this site is NOT to solve homework and exams for you. You said this is not from homework or exam, but that what someone that is trying to cheat in his exam would say. Are we supposed to take your word for it?

Comment: @PONPON The context you provide needs to be *part of the question*, not a weird, passive aggressive list of Q&As.

Comment: @jjagmath Please do not engage in edit wars.

Comment: @EverybodyElse  I am locking this question for 24 hours so that everyone has a chance to cool down.  Let this topic rest for a little bit, and come back when you can engage in a more civil and productive manner.

Comment: PONPON, I would rather your question be opened rather than closed but there is basically no way that anyone will vote to reopen your question when your add context like this that needlessly takes up more than 13 times the vertical length than your actual question. Parcly has done a good job 'trimming the fat'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is such a function, by the mean-value theorem, $f’(p)=\lim_{x\rightarrow p}\frac{f(x)-f(p)}{x-p}\leq 0$. This contradicts $f’(p)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \ne p$. By the mean value theorem there is $t_x$ between $x$ and $p$ such that $t_x \ne x , t_x \ne p$ and

$$\frac{f(x)-f(p)}{x-p}= f'(t_x).$$

Since $t \ne x $ we get

$$\frac{f(x)-f(p)}{x-p} \le 0.$$

hence

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow p}\frac{f(x)-f(p)}{x-p}\leq 0,$$

It follows that $f'(p) \le 0.$ A contradiction.

Comment: The question which you have answered here does not meet the quality standards for the site, as it consists of little more than a problem statement and the assertion that the asker "knows basic calculus".  Please help us to maintain quality standards on this site by refraining from answering such questions.  Instead, why not use the comments to help the asker provide some additional details to improve the quality of the question?  or try to find a duplicate question?  For additional information, please read [this recent announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/).

Answer (score -3):

If $f'$ is continuous, then obviously not, that's basic calculus.
If you are willing to use distributions, you'll have to work on what $f'(p)>0$ means, but then you can indeed provide an example, use the Heaviside function and $p=0$.